# PHP MIB to OID resolve

Tags: php, snmp, mib

I'm googling around for a couple of days, and can't find clear method/lib for resolving OID from MIB name, and MIB from OID.

I've found few sites that have a large MIB database, search functions ie. but communicate with them needs cURL/socket connectivity and regexp of results (or eval in some cases)

I've tried to parse MIB files myself, but this is returning to writing language parser in php witch, is "madness" ;)

I have storage/cache mechanism witch work well, and every MIB lockup has to be done only once, but this one lockup must be fast and reliable

**[EDIT]** heh and forgot about clearing the point, is there any tool/lib/method fast and reliable to lockup MIBs and OIDs?

Comment: I assume you've looked at PHP's snmp module http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.snmp.php

Comment: Yeah... It can read MIB database, but there is no way i know witch i can use to extract this database to readable format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have net-snmp installed, and you can execute programs from your PHP script, you can use `snmptranslate` to go from a name to a mib:

```
snmptranslate -IR sysName.0
```

This tool depends on having your MIBDIRS and MIBS environment variables set, or supplying appropriate command arguments. (See `man snmpcmd` for details on the env vars and/or args.)

Comment: That is not clear answer, but i have dumped all MIBs i have in my machine, and ready to go DB i have put into server, but thx for this :)